# Get TimeZoneOffset - Java

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I am trying to get "TimeZoneOffset" in java and with reference to [this](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.util.TimeZone), I implemented this:

```
long unix_time_at_midnight;
DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d = new Date((unix_time*1000)/1000);
String d1 = dateFormat.format(d);
unix_time_at_midnight = Long.parseLong(d1);
int m=TimeZone.getOffset(unix_time_at_midnight) ;
```

I get "The method getOffset(int, int, int, int, int, int) in the type TimeZone is not applicable for the arguments (long)". Can anyone guide?

Comment: According to what reference exactly?

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: Edited my question with the link. I am working in Eclipse with BlackBerry Plugin. I am unable to get the TimeZoneOffset; the difference between the UTC and local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Timezone.getOffset(int era, int year, int month, int day, int dayOfWeek, int milliseconds);` is an abstract class and one has to reference it from a implemented `Timezone` subclass.

You're trying to access a non-static method statically, and the compiler is matching it to the abstract method.

The solution you're seeking of is:

```
int m=TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(unix_time_at_midnight) ;
```

---

**EDIT**: Looking on [`TimeZone`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/java/util/TimeZone.html) on BlackBerry API, I see there is no `getOffset(long date)` method, but [`getOffset(int era, int year, int month, int day, int dayOfWeek, int millis)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

A possible solution might be:

```
Date d = new Date((unix_time*1000)/1000)
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
c.setTime(d);
int m = tz.getOffset(1, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Comment: I still get the same error message as quoted above because getOffset does not accept a long value.

Comment: Updated my post to fit the RIM BlackBerry API.